# setShouldCache(false) not working

Tags: java, android, android-volley

i have log in code who connecting to my php file on my host using volley
everything works great but when i log off and log in again, saved cache memory remember my old information even if i changed it.

i tried to use:
requestQueue.getCache().clear();
stringRequest.setShouldCache(false);

not clearing my cache

this is my code:

```
private void sendRequest(){
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,DBConstants.LOG_IN_USER + mEmail + "&password=" + mPassword,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    JSONArray user = null;
                    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                    try {
                        jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        user = jsonObject.getJSONArray(JSON_ARRAY);
                        JSONObject jo = user.getJSONObject(0);
                        gates = new ArrayList<String>(5);
                        gateData = new ArrayList<String>();
                        mEmail = jo.getString(DBConstants.KEY_LOGIN_EMAIL);
                        mPassword = jo.getString(DBConstants.KEY_LOGIN_PASSWORD);
                        name = jo.getString(DBConstants.KEY_LOGIN_NAME);
                        if(!mEmail.equals("null")) {
                            level = Integer.parseInt(jo.getString(DBConstants.KEY_LOGIN_LEVEL));
                            for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
                                gates.add(jo.getString(DBConstants.KEY_LOGIN_GATE + i));
                                if(!gates.get(i-1).equals("null")) {
                                    for (String dataString : gates.get(i-1).split(";")) {
                                        gateData.add(dataString);
                                    }
                                    newGate = new Gate(gateData.get(0),gateData.get(1),gateData.get(2),
                                            Integer.parseInt(gateData.get(3)),Integer.parseInt(gateData.get(4)),gateData.get(5));
                                    myHandler.addNewGate(newGate);
                                    getAuthorizedList(newGate);
                                    gateData.clear();
                                }
                            }
                            login = true;
                        } else {
                            login = false;
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    login = false;
                }
            });
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this.getApplicationContext());
    requestQueue.getCache().clear();
    stringRequest.setShouldCache(false);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry you can close
on my hosting account i had cache manager, i turned it off and it works great!